# Order of installations of fusion middleware components

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, middleware, fusion

I am required to install the following Oracle fusion middleware components for a project using chef (I know how to use chef so that is not a problem).

OHS, WLS, JRockit. SOA, OSB, oracle_common, ODI, AIA.

I am going to setup an oracle database first. After doing that I am not sure of the steps that I need to follow. What do I install first? Does one of these depend on each other? Just need to know the order of installation for all these. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/overview/quickstartguidesoasuite11gr1ps4-459545.pdf) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/SOA/entry/installing_oracle_soa_suite_11).
And Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/install.1111/e14318/qisoa.htm#BABJFDIA).
I always:
1. Install DB (note there are setup scripts to run after install to size the DB for the SW.)
2. Install jRocket
3. Install WLS.
4. Install Binaries (SOA Suite...).
5. Run RCU to configure the DB schemas.
6. Create the WLS domain.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Thats what confuses me. the document says install the database then weblogic server then RCU and then SOA. Unfortunately, I dont have an option of trying the installers manually (cant argue with the boss). Since I will be using chef, I will have to run it via cookbook with response files (provided to me already) . So I am thinking if order of installation is important or can i follow any order..

Comment: you can install the binaries (WLS, DB and FMW/SOA) in any order. BUT, the db must be configured per the scripts THEN run RCU then create the Domain - as domain creation requires the acct/schema info created by RCU. hth.

Comment: cool .. thanks a lot. let me try it out and will post if I need any more suggestions. thanks again.